# Conisder an equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let
$$x^n=Ax^{n−1}+Bx^{n−2}$$
and, removing the common factor $x^{n−2}$, we get
$$x^2=Ax+B=0$$

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct solutions of the equation, then also
$$ * x^n=cx^n_1+dx^n_2$$ for some constant $c,d$.*
And now I don't understand why. I highlighted it with *

Comment: By $x^n$, do you mean $x$ to the power $n$ or $x$ superscript $n$? It looks like recursive equation... By the way, should $Ax+B=0$? Or do you only mean $x^2=Ax+B$?

Comment: Hint: Induction on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct solutions of the Quadratic $x^2-Ax-B=0$ implies, $x_1^2-Ax_1-B=0\tag{1}$ $x_2^2-Ax_2-B=0\tag{2}$ Which gives, $x_1^n-Ax_1^{n-1}-Bx_1^{n-1}=0\tag{3}$ $x_2^n-Ax_2^{n-1}-Bx_2^{n-1}=0\tag{4}$

$\begin{align}\therefore x^n-Ax^{n-1}-Bx^{n-2} &=\left(cx_1^n+dx_2^n\right)-A\left(cx_1^{n-1}+dx_2^{n-1}\right)-B\left(cx_1^{n-2}+dx_2^{n-2}\right)\\&=c\left(x_1^n-Ax_1^{n-1}-Bx_2^{n-2}\right)+d\left(x_2^n-Ax_2^{n-1}-Bx_2^{n-1}\right)\\&=0\end{align}$